# Why does a copy of a dictionary not change the original dict when we give a new key-value but does change when using append?

Tags: python, dictionary

For example, say we have two dicts:

```
dict_one = {'color': ['red', 'blue']}
dict_two = {'color': 'red'}
```

And then we make a copy of the second dict:

`copy_d2 = dict_two.copy()`

And then we add the key `'color'` and a value `'green'` to the copied dict:

`copy_d2['color'] = 'green'`

When I print dict_two:

`print(dict_two)`

I get back the original dict (unchanged)

`{'color': 'red'}`

Question, does the original value in the original "dict_two" change here? Reason being, because it is a string?

Another part, say I use append on dict_one instead:

```
copy_d1 = dict_one.copy()
copy_d1['color'].append('green')
```

now when I use print:

`print(dict_one)`

I get back:

`{'color': ['red', 'blue', 'green']}`

So the original dict_one has 'green' in there as well.
Does this have something do with the fact that the value of the key for dict_one is a list, whereas dict_two is a string?

why does the first one simply change the copied dict's elements but not the original? But when I have a dictionary with a list and use 'append' on it, it is as if there is a pointer/reference to the original dict, and changes made to the copy get persisted to the original.

Can someone please explain what is going on here?

Thanks

Comment: `string` and `list` are treated in different way. It duplicate `string`, but it doesn't duplicate `list` but only copy reference to this `list`. You would have to use `copy_d1 = copy.deepcopy(dict_one)` to duplicate also `list`.

Comment: BTW: you have the same problem when you use normal `one = "red"` and `two = one` and later `one = "green"` - it doesn't change `two`. And `one = ["red"]` and `two = one` and `one.append("green")` - it changes `two` because both have reference to the same list.

Comment: @furas is this something that is unique to storing lists inside of dicts? So when I have dict of only strings, then it duplicates it fine? But this isnt a hard/deep copy only a shallow one (copy fn). But if I do the same where it is a dict full of strings and lists this wont actually duplicate the list -- instead making a reference to the original list in the dict?

Comment: @furas the part about strings is interesting. So if I wanted to change a string that resides inside a dict, I cant just shallow copy the dict and do: ```copy_d2["index"]=value``` to change it, bc it doesn't allow reference copies to strings to be updated/changed?

Comment: it is NOT unique to storing `list` in `dict` but this is always when you use `list` in any place - directly in variable (and assign it to different variable without coping) or inside other `list` or in `dict` or in `class` (and you use shallow copy to duplicate list/dict/class)` or you send `list` to function. Assigning to other variable only copy reference and `shallow copy` also only copy reference to nested list. And the same problem is with dictionary and class.

Comment: maybe run some code on https://pythontutor.com/ to vizualize problem - you will see references as arrows.